# How do I use function keys in Firefox under Android?

Tags: android, firefox, keyboard

I have an HTML app that I am trying to use on Android under the latest Firefox beta (mobile).  However, I am running into several problems that I need solutions for.

1. My Android device (a phone) has virtually no keys aside from letters, numbers, and punctuation, but my HTML app relies heavily on the keyboard to do various things.  For instance, the Insert key and function keys, which are not present on the phone.
2. I can solve this problem with the Hacker's keyboard, as it provides these function keys, but I can't get the keyboard to come up, unless I tap in a text field.  If there is no text field, I can't get the keyboard to come up, even if the page is listening for keys.  How do I force the keyboard to come up whenever I want?
3. Even if there is a text field and I tap on it and Hacker's keyboard comes up, when I hit a function key using it, I don't get any keyboard events.  I know that it says some apps might not respond but I would expect Firefox would since that is required of it by javascript.  How do I get the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can activate the setting "Show persistent notification" in Hacker's Keyboard. This adds a notification icon, and tapping that opens the keyboard unconditionally.

This still isn't a complete solution to your problem - last time I tried this, cursor keys still just moved the screen content and didn't get reported as key events to Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, that suggestion is helpful - although I should note that tapping the persistent notification does not work if I have my physical keyboard slid out, which is annoying.  I'll accept this answer as it appears that problem 3 is a bug in Firefox itself.